# Vim behavior differs on saving files

Tags: linux, vim

Currently I'm writing a python script to implement file watching using pyinotify on linux. What's different from other tools is that auditd logs are used to enrich the output.

On several systems my script works like a charm but one system shows another behavior on editing files using vim: On some systems files gets written using

```
/etc/login.defs OPEN
/etc/login.defs ACCESS
/etc/login.defs ACCESS
/etc/login.defs CLOSE_NOWRITE,CLOSE
/etc/login.defs MODIFY
/etc/login.defs OPEN
/etc/login.defs MODIFY
/etc/login.defs MODIFY
/etc/login.defs CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE
/etc/login.defs ATTRIB
/etc/login.defs OPEN
/etc/login.defs ACCESS
/etc/login.defs ACCESS
/etc/login.defs CLOSE_NOWRITE,CLOSE
/etc/login.defs OPEN
/etc/login.defs ACCESS
/etc/login.defs CLOSE_NOWRITE,CLOSE
```

Thats nice, because diffing the files leads to clean results. On other systems vim behaves like this on writing files:

```
/etc/login.defs MOVE_SELF
/etc/login.defs ATTRIB
/etc/login.defs DELETE_SELF
...
creating a new file
```

Can someone explain why vim shows this behavior and how I'm able to force vim on my test system to behave the same way so I'm able handle it?

The environment:
Debain 9.7
vim Version: 2:8.0.0197-4+deb9u1

Answer (score 0):

I think you're seeing different results due to Vim's backup options. By default, Vim moves away the original file, writes the updated file contents to a different (temp) file name, then renames it to the original file, and finally removes the moved-away original. This ensures that no data is lost even if something bad happens in between.

The behavior is controlled by the `'backup'` and `'writebackup'` Vim options. See [`:help backup-table`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/editing.txt.html#backup-table) for a detailed explanation.

For *inotify* observations, the default behavior is problematic. You can try `:set nowritebackup`, but this increases the risk of data loss, unless you also `:set backup`.

Comment: also relevant `:h 'backupcopy'` and `:h 'backupskip'`

Comment: I once checked Vim's way to write files, see this answer: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/18563/19763